# Partitioning sets

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Consider the set $S=\{3,4,5,\dots,n\}$. Let $A$ and $B$ be two partitions of $S$ such that there does not exist a triplet $(a,b,c)$ in either $A$ or $B$ such that $ab=c$ (note that $a$ and $b$ are not necessarily distinct). Find the largest value of $n$ such that a partitioning is possible.

After some experimentation, I see that $n=9, 10, 11,..., 16$ are feasible. Whenever $A$ contains a triplet $(a,b,c)$ such that $ab=c$, we can place one or two of $a, b, c$ into $B$. But I'm not sure how to determine a value of $n$ for which it is impossible to find a desired partitioning. I think it would be useful to find a way to determine how a partitioning is impossible.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? It has already been posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490342/partition-the-given-subset-according-to-condition) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489974/partitioning-the-set-given-the-condition#3489974)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by almagest in the comments, $n$ must be smaller than 243.

It just so happens that a feasible example for $n=242$ is easy to construct.

Take 
$$
A = \{3,\dots, 8, 81, \dots, 242\},
$$

$$
B = \{9,\dots, 80\}.
$$

Comment: This does not take you very far. It is easy to see that $n<243$. If $3\in A$, then $9\in B$, so $81\in A$, so $27\in B$. Now 243 cannot go into either $A$ or $B$.

Comment: Yup. I'll try to see if there's something more I can squeeze out of this idea.

Comment: @almagest Knowing that, it's actually quite simple...

Comment: +1 That is really neat! Well done! I wasted a lot of time looking at more complicated approaches.